# Looking for a free interactive USA map with states that highlight

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am looking for a free interactive map like this "http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html" or even like this "http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#usa-states"  The first one i had trouble implementing the javascript to where it would highlight.  I'm also not very fond of this map "http://www.fedstats.gov/qf/".  Could anyone help me?  Even if i did the first one i would have to resize it to fit and all the coords would be off.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Geo Chart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) and set the region to be the US

Comment: I've tried looking at that and can't figure it out.  I set region but can not get it to work, and also don't know how i will pass the state clicks on.

Answer (score 0):

Maps:
http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:SVG_maps_of_the_United_States

Library that might help (check out the map example):
http://raphaeljs.com/